# How to click an element that's not visible in Cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

I got this error running a test in Cypress:

```
Timed out retrying after 10050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:
```

How can I click on it anyway? It's just a menu item and I don't need it to be visible for my test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to add `{force: true}` and it should make the click happen:

```
cy.get('locator').click({force: true})
```

Comment: You can use the parent and child elements 
cy.get('parentSelector').find('childSelector').click()

Comment: Isn't Cypress supposed to auto scroll to the element in recent version? I keep getting this issue back suddenly