# data-cy exists in DOM tree but not visible

Tags: javascript, html, material-ui, cypress, regression-testing

I need some clarification on the usage of Cypress. I'm writing some e2e tests and one of them failed, because the element is not visible.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440620/how-to-click-an-element-thats-not-visible-in-cypress) helpful, it solved my problem. Clicking element which is reported to be not visible.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="dApp Info"]').click({force: true});
```

But now I'm wondering about Cypress best practice.

For example, let's say I have a component, which I want to click. It's a link `a` inside a `div`, inside a `div`, inside a `nav`. (I gave the link the `data-cy` property.)  Even though as a user, the component is visible and clickable (see 1st image), the component is reported not to be visible (see 2nd image).

Is it best practice to add a `data-cy` property to any element I want to click and just use `.click({force: true})` or should I add a `data-cy` property to one of the `div`s which wrap my actual link and click those (is that even possible?)?

[image]

[image: not visible]

### Edit

##### DOM Structure

```
<nav data-cy="sidebar-nav-studio">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <ul data-cy="dApp-sub-section-sidebar-nav-studio">
      <span>
       <a data-cy="Add Templates">
        <div> </div>
        <div>
         <p>
         Add Templates
         </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a data-cy="Look & Feel">
       <div> </div>
       <div>
        <p>
         Look & Feel
        </p>
      </div>
     </a>
     <a data-cy="dApp Info">
      <div> </div>
      <div>
       <p>
       dApp Info
       </p>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding the `data-cy` attribute to the `a` tag would be a good option, so that you get the element as visible and click it. What I understood from the [cypress best practices page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#How-It-Works), the `data-cy` or `data-test` or `data-testid` should be added to the target element, which in your case is the `a` tag.

I would suggest you to not use `click({force: true})` until absolutely required because it forces the action and disables waiting for actionability.

By actionability, cypress means commands that simulate a user interacting with your application. Under the hood, Cypress fires the events a browser would fire thus causing your application's event bindings to fire.

So in case, a real user is not able to see or interact with a button for some reason, then the test should fail, but with `force:true`, the test will pass because it bypasses the actionability checks and forcefully clicks the button. You can read more about [Actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Actionability) and [Forcing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Forcing) from the docs.

Or in case you don't want to use any tags, one good way would be to use the combination of a selector and inner text value to find the element and click it, something like:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="sidebar-nav-studio"]').click() //opens the nav
cy.contains('a', 'dApp Info').click()
```

Comment: I tried `cy.contains('a', 'dApp-Info')` but it has 0 matched elements, even though I can see it in the element inspector. What do I need that it matches my elements?

Comment: Can you add your HTML DOM structure?

Comment: I added the DOM structure

Comment: There's an extra `-` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Fody Thanks for pointing out. Yves Boutellier Updated my answer.

Comment: `cy.get('[data-cy=sidebar-nav-studio]').contains('a', 'dApp Info').click();` does not work

Comment: @Yves remove the `cy.get('[data-cy=sidebar-nav-studio]')`and just use`cy.contains('a', 'dApp Info')` will fetch that element based on selector and inner text. This is assuming that your drop down is open. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Actions

If clicking the link is just a way to take action (i.e get to another page) using `{force:true}` is pragmatic.

#### Regressions

On the other hand, if you want to test for ***regressions in the menu system itself*** forcing might be the wrong thing to do.

Events bubble from one element to another, so it might not be necessary to click the `<a>` directly.

Try clicking up the parent element chain until you find the wrapper that's both visible and clickable.

#### Framework libraries

Using a mainstream library like Material UI, it's not necessary to test functionality that is provided by that library.

You can trust that the library builders have already tested it.

So a test like "Does this menu open?" is probably wasting your time (although configuration of the library isn't).

---

### Selecting MUI Menu without force-clicking

Just tried out the sample Material UI menu given in the docs, and you can click the item without using `{force:true}`.

I'm guessing the step you are missing is opening the menu so that the items are visible.

```js
cy.get('.MuiButton-root').click()            // open the dropdown
cy.get('[data-cy="dApp Info"]').click()      // clicks without forcing
```

Note that the Nav to open the menu is not located near the menu items, in fact the items appear to be lazy-loaded (not in DOM until menu is opened).

Comment: what does that mean "test for regressions in the menu system itself" ?

Comment: Can only give a for-instance, but menu items can be hidden until you open the menu. If your menu item remains hidden due to change (regression) in source and you use `{force:true}` on it, you will not pick up the error.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot accept two answers, even though both are good.

Comment: No worries! I think the example I tested is not the same as your code anyway. It's a pity you did not get two up-votes!

Answer (score 2):

I would use these selectors

```js
cy.contains('button', 'DApp').click()
cy.contains('a[data-cy="dApp Info"]', 'dApp Info').click()
```

I agree that using `.click({force:true})` is a code-smell.